# Visual Studio - Creation of a .dll without .lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

why it has happened to me now that in Visual Studio 10 (C++) the .dll has been created but not the .lib ? Usually the .lib was created along with the .dll, by specifying "Dynamic Library (.dll)" as value for the property Configuration type in the General section of the project Properties...
This time instead, in order to obtain the .lib I had to specify "Static library (.lib)" as option in the same field of the General section.
I would add also that by generating the .lib, .dll in the same building dir has been removed during the generation process... :(

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if you don't explicitly export anything - you get a .dll but no .lib.

Make sure you understand how to use the [dllexport/dllimport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx) attributes correctly. You need to specify which parts of the code comprise the interface to your dll. Put simply - only the parts that are exported are included in the import lib.